# Prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: number-theory

I'd need a help with an exercise. I am trying to show that $(1-i)$ is a prime (or principal equivalently) ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. For doing this, I have not worked on the norms yet so I can't use those to prove it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My first instinct would be to try showing that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1-i)$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(a+bi)(c+di)=1-i$, with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$, so that $ac-bd=1$ and $bc+ad=-1$. Squaring those last two equations, and adding the results,
$$
(ac-bd)^2+(bc+ad)^2=(-1)^2+1
$$
$$
(ac)^2+(bd)^2+(bc)^2+(ad)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=2
$$
Since $2$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$, and both $a^2+b^2,c^2+d^2\in\mathbb Z$, without loss of generality, $a^2+b^2=1$. The only solution to this over the integers is $a=\pm1$ and $b=0$, or $a=0$ and $b=\pm1$. Either way, $a+bi$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$\phi: \Bbb Z[i]\to\Bbb Z_2:=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;\;,\;\;\;\phi(a+bi):=a^2+b^2\pmod 2$$

Check $\;\phi\;$ is a ring homomorphism (Careful! It seems like it is *not*, but it actually is).

Now, let us find

$$\ker\phi=\left\{\;a+bi\in\Bbb Z[i]\;\;:\;\;a^2=b^2\pmod 2\;\right\}=\left\{\;a+bi\in\Bbb Z[i]\;:\;\;a=b\pmod2\;\right\}=$$

$$=\left\{\;a+bi\in\Bbb Z\;:\;\exists\,r,s\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;\;a=r+s\,,\,\,b=-r+s\;\right\}=$$

$$=\left\{\;a+bi\in\Bbb Z[i]\;:\;a+bi=(r+si)(1-i)\;\right\}=\langle\;1-i\;\rangle$$

Comment: While true, that's sort of an odd way to present the homomorphism: the more usual way is to specify the image of $i$ and let everything else follow from that.

Comment: @Hurkyl Perhaps, yet the OP stated he hasn't even worked with norms yet, so perhaps he'll be able to understand this better.